# A hashmap of list of strings gives me OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, hashmap

A line in my program which declares a Hashmap triggers an error.

```
public class SubjectTeacherPeriod{
private int id;

private Map<String, Integer> num_attribute_map; 
private Map<String,List<String>> str_attribute_map; 

private Period period;
private List<Period> periodList;

public SubjectTeacherPeriod(){
    num_attribute_map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    str_attribute_map = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();  //THIS LINE
}
 ....
```

is responsible for:

```
jesvin@Jesvin-Technovia:~/dev/drools/timetabler$ java -server in.co.technovia.timetabler.TimeTableApp
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.HashMap.<init>(HashMap.java:226)
    at in.co.technovia.timetabler.domain.SubjectTeacherPeriod.<init>(SubjectTeacherPeriod.java:38)
    at in.co.technovia.timetabler.solution.TimeTableInitializer.createTimeTable(TimeTableInitializer.java:66)
    at in.co.technovia.timetabler.TimeTableApp.main(TimeTableApp.java:37)
```

What is wrong with my hashmap?

---

**Update:** just like all answers guessed, a bad loop variable created too many variables. It was not a problem of the hashmap itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your hash map. (How could it be? You're just declaring it / instantiating it.)

My guess would be that you're creating an enormous number of `SubjectTeacherPeriod` objects which basically fills the memory with hash maps. In the end it doesn't have room for one more.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not an application bug and you're legitimately adding a colossal amount of data to your HashMaps, see this article about how to increase your heap space.

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space.html

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to:

1. Verify that you're not allocating more `SubjectTeacherPeriod` objects than are needed.
2. Increase the size of the memory allocation pool. See option -Xmx for the java executable.